# How to handle a suspected troll?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

Consider the question [What are file systems?](https://superuser.com/questions/1280411/what-are-file-systems) - there is no indication of what research the querent has done, and punching the title into Google generates a bunch of links to sites (including Wikipedia) that give good useful explanations. It's a low-quality question, certainly, but I believe that flagging it as such is inappropriate, as the quality *could* be improved by the querent, without much effort. On the other hand, I 'just have this feeling' that there *won't* be any improvement, even though I've prompted the querent to try to improve it.

Should I just leave it unflagged, and hope that the querent takes the hint, or is there an appropriate flag for this?

Comment: It's not a troll, it's just a terrible question.

Comment: VLQ flag? In any case I've already closed it as too broad.

Comment: @DavidPostill - yes, I noticed that, almost before I was done posting _this_ question.

Comment: @djsmiley2k - It's certainly a VLQ, but it's on a topic that's just so elementary that I can't seriously believe that the querent really doesn't understand the concept even after (allegedly) doing research; the 'gut feeling' said to me that he was looking for responses that he could use as an excuse for abusive behavior or some such.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin A question being “elementary” doesn’t make it a bad question

Comment: @Ramhound - The querent was sufficiently well-versed on the subject of computers to have earned at least 262 rep on SU (he had 363 when I saw the question). No, a question being "elementary" doesn't inherently make it a bad question, but one can certainly note that a combination of factors makes the whole thing seem "off". Or perhaps I'm just overly sensitive to the possibility of trolls, after participating in [this (now deleted) StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942271/how-to-work-with-files-in-remote-folder)

Comment: At the end of the day the proper action was taken.

Comment: And thus answered the question as to how I should have flagged it, had I been less uncertain.